# So where did I go wrong or otherwise left derivability at a point won't imply left continuity!

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

> $$\text{REVISED}$$

Consider the function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R:\begin{cases}\sqrt x,&x\in[0,1)\\2,&x=1\\\end{cases}$

$f$ is not left continuous at $1$ since there is no $c\in(0,1)$ such that $|f(x)-f(1)|<\frac{1}{2}~\forall$ $x\in(c,1].$

But when I'm trying to verify the existence of the left derivative of $f$ at $1$ amazingly it comes out to be left derivable at $1$ since $Lf'(c)=\lim_{x\to1^-}\dfrac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1}g|_{[0,1))}(x)$ exists (where $g:[0,1)\cup(1,\infty)\to\mathbb R:x\mapsto\dfrac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\dfrac{\sqrt x-2}{x-1}$) which follows from the fact that $\sqrt x$ is differentiable at $1.$

So where did I go wrong or otherwise left derivability at a point won't imply left continuity there!

**Added:** And one more thing. if $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R:\begin{cases}\sqrt x,&x\in[0,1)\\-2,&x=1\\\end{cases}$ then even though $Lf'(1)=\dfrac{d}{dx}(\sqrt x)|_{x=1}>0,$ $f$ is not increasing at $1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(1)$ is $2$, not $\sqrt{1}$.

[*Edit in response to the revised question:*]

Now you've just written $2$ where you had $\sqrt1$ before, but now the justification you give ("which follows from the fact that $\sqrt x$ is differentiable at $1$") no longer applies, since it would have to be $1$, not $2$, for this to be the differential quotient of $\sqrt x$.

Comment: please clarify in details sir.

Comment: @Sriti: I see that you've revised the question based on my answer after posting the above comment. Note that you can delete confusing outdated comments by clicking on the cross that appears when you hover over them.

Answer (score 0):

$\{x_n\}\subset[0,1)$ with $x_n\to 1\implies u_n=\dfrac{\sqrt x_n-2}{x_n-1}\to\infty$ since $\dfrac{2}{1-x_n}\le u_n~\forall~n\in\mathbb Z^+.$

So $\lim_{x\to 1}g|_{[0,1)}(x)$ doesn't exist.